# Expand partition in Gparted backwards vs. move backwards + expand

Tags: partition, gparted

Which is quicker and safer?:

- To enlarge a Gparted partition backwards

or:

- To move the original (smaller) partition backwards, and then enlarge it?

**Example demonstration**

Enlarge `/dev/sda3` to fill the unallocated space.

[image]
<sub>(source: [fritzhardy.com](http://blog.fritzhardy.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/sda2_unallocated.jpeg))</sub>